# How to prevent the floating layout wrapping when firefox zoom is reduced

Tags: css, firefox, zooming, css-float, word-wrap

Given the following HTML. It display two columns: `#left`, `#right`. Both are fixed width and have 1px borders. Width and borders equal the size of upper container: `#wrap`.

When I zoom out Firefox 3.5.2 by pressing Ctrl+- columns get wrapped ([demo](http://grotezo.ee/wrap.html)).

How to prevent this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      div           {float:left}
      #wrap         {width:960px}
      #left, #right {width:478px;border:1px solid}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="wrap">
      <div id="left">
        left
      </div>
      <div id="right">
        right
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 13):

Try switching to a different [box model](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html) as follows:

```
#left, #right 
{ 
  width:480px;
  border:1px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  /* and for older/other browsers: */
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box
}
```

Comment: This solved my problem. I used the Compass mix-in: http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/box_sizing/

Comment: Can anyone explain why it happens? I had the same problem on my site, [Goodwill Fire 18](http://www.goodwillfire18.com/). Both the "News Feed" and the right sidebar are floated left and right. The right sidebar has a border, similar to the OP's. When you zoom out in Firefox, it puts the right sidebar on the bottom.

Answer (score 8):

Dmitri,

When the browser caluclates the new width of your divs after you zoom, it doesn't have reduce the two 478px+4px of border elements in proportion to the single 960px.  So you end up with this:

**Your original styles:**

```
#wrap equals 960px wide
#left & #right, plus border equals 960px wide
```

Everything fits nicely.

**Zoom reduced (ctrl-)**

```
#wrap equals (approx.) 872px wide.
#left, #right, plus border eqauls 876px wide.
(left and right reduce to approx 436px each, plus 4 px of border)
```

Contents are too wide for #wrap.  To see & measure this just apply a background color to #wrap.

To fix, remove width from #wrap.  Because it is floated, it will shink to fit the contents.  However, you should apply a width to floated elements and your div {float:left} applies it to #wrap.

Remove the style div {float:left} and add float:left to #left, #right.

```
#left, #right {float:left;width:478px;border:1px solid}
```

If you want #wrap to be centered, then you'll need to declare a width for it again and add margin:0 auto;, in which case you'll have this problem again [edit: or you can, as chris indicated, set the width to 100%].  So simply recalculate the width of #left, #right so that they will fit.

It's my understanding that leaving a little breathing room between the width of parent and child elements is good to avoid this sort of problem anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue described above. After, hopelessly wandering around the internet for a few minutes, I found out that apparently it's a bug in `Firefox 3.5.x` and `IE 7/8`. The bug is still present as of this writing.

To see more about the bug go here: http://markasunread.com/?p=61 (formerly http://markasunread.com/2009/06/zoom-bug-in-ie78-and-firefox-caused-by-border/)

Comment: Bug still exists on Firefox 29.0.1

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem. Setting #right to a negative margin worked. For example:

```
#right{
    margin-right:-400px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand your situation. Reducing the zoom should in effect zoom out. Are you saying that when you zoom out the columns wrap around?

You should float those divs using this code in your CSS:

```
#container {width: 960px}
#left {float: left}
#right {float: right}
```

If this does not work you can try leaving a small space between the columns by adjusting the width to compensate for some small browser discrepancies.

**EDITED** (ignore above):

Seeing as you have provided me with more information, I need to tell you that the browser incorporates rounding when resizing and having these exact pixel-perfect sizing isn't the smartest thing to do.

Instead, you can have one div have an absolute width and the other to have an automatic width like so:

```
#container {width: 960px;}
#left {width: 478px;}
#right {width: auto;}
```

This will have the browser take as much space for #right as can be possibly taken inside the #wrap div. Be sure to set a width for the wrap, otherwise it will take 100% of the window.

I hope this helps!

**EDITED**:

Right IS very close to your fixed width, because you defined the width of your container already, so it is simply the container width subtracted by the width of the left side. This is merely to ensure that there is no discrepancy when resizing the window.

I understand it will not take up the entire area of space, however, as content is added, the maximum it will go is container - left width. Are you trying to apply a background? In that case set the right side background as the container background and then the left side as the left side background (make sure it covers half of it).

I hope I've helped.

Comment: I extended my question with demo. Right and left float will not help. Reducing width of the columns helps but is it only one available option?

Comment: #right {width: auto;} helps with wrapping but this do not make #right fixed width. If #right do not have enough content then it will be smaller than 478px;

Answer (score 1):

I was wrestling with this bug too.  I had a tab navigation with fixed widths on each tab and a right margin all totaling the width of the container div.

I actually discovered a new solution, which seems to work great.  The tab navigation is of course wrapped in a ul tag.  I set a width on this ul tag of about 6px greater than the container div.  So for example, container div is 952px wide, then ul tag is 958px wide.  Since the li tags in the navigation are floated to the left and have fixed widths, they will not go beyond 952px, however the ul element has some breathing room, which appears to be necessary to squash this bug.  I've tried zooming out in Firefox and IE7/8 and the tabs stay in place.

Hope this helps someone save a few minutes/hours!

Answer (score 1):

Ok guys, when you have a div with fixed height, to prevent zoom from breaking up everything, add `overflow:hidden` to it's css. That did the trick for me and now every browser can go zoom crazy. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the width of your #wrap.

I've set the width to 100% and it doesn't break anymore in Firefox while zooming out with CTRL -.

Comment: Yes, but if they want to set the width to 960px for a reason (say, to use the 960.gs grid system) or if they would like to center the contents, they'll need to set a width for the container.

Answer (score 0):

Best Solution to fix floating bug in every case is use table layout using tds.
That will never loose floating.