# HTML navigation float with border PROBLEM

Tags: html, css, firefox

Seriously, when I'm applying borders then use floats, this problem occurs! When I'm trying to zoom out, the display messes up. This topic is the best example of my problem, [How to prevent the floating layout wrapping when firefox zoom is reduced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274151/how-to-prevent-the-floating-layout-wrapping-when-firefox-zoom-is-reduced). I search through the internet but all of the questions haven't been answered clearly, as if there's no official fix for this.

This is my navigation that when you zoom out, the last bar messes up and going at the bottom.
http://angelickp.byethost24.com/Church.php

Tried with IE and firefox.

Comment: works fine in Opera 11. It's clearly a rounding error where the browser rounds width of your elements,borders,padding up and ends up slightly more than the width of the parent. What if you define the width of each of the elements as `33%`, you'll have 1% for the rounding errors.

Answer (score 0):

When you zoom out, the border width values will change. [This](http://markasunread.com/2009/06/zoom-bug-in-ie78-and-firefox-caused-by-border/) may help you.