# How do I keep this bar from breaking?

Tags: html, css

How do I keep a navigation bar from breaking when zooming out?

Here is my code:-

```
<nav>
<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">What We Do</a></li>
<li><a href="#">How we deliver</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Who We Are</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Our Partners</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

Here's my CSS :-

```
#nav {
margin:80px 0 40px; 
list-style:none;
text-shadow: 0 -1px 3px #202020;
width:880px; 
height:34px;
-moz-border-radius:4px;
-webkit-border-radius:4px;
border-radius:8px 8px 8px 8px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px #cecece;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px #cecece;
box-shadow: 0 3px 3px #8b8b8b;
letter-spacing:-1px;
font-family:Calibri;
font-size:18px;
letter-spacing:-0.5px;
font-weight:500;
}
#nav li {
display:block; 
float:left;
width:124px;
height:34px;
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(0,100,145) 20%, rgb(0,129,187) 80%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(0,100,145) 20%, rgb(0,129,187) 80%);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.0,        rgb(0,100,145)), color-stop(0.62, rgb(0,129,187)));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(0,100,145) 20%, rgb(0,129,187)     80%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(0,100,145) 20%, rgb(0,129,187) 80%);
background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(0,100,145) 20%, rgb(0,129,187) 80%);
background-color:#007fb9;
border-style:solid;
border-width:1px;
border-color:#005F82 #004A66 #005F82 #005D7F;
transition:all 0.5s ease 0s;
}
#nav li:hover {
background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(center bottom , #006491 100%, #0081BB 0%);
}
#nav li a {
text-decoration:none;
color:#FFF;
text-align:center;
color:white;
outline:medium none;
line-height:32px;
display:block;
}
#nav li:first-child {
-moz-border-radius:4px 0 0 4px;
-webkit-border-radius:4px 0 0 4px;
border-radius:10px 0 0 10px;
border-left:none;
}
#nav li:last-child {
-moz-border-radius:4px 0 0 4px;
-webkit-border-radius:4px 0 0 4px;
border-radius:0 10px 10px 0;
border-right:none;
width:124px;
}
nav {
width:890px;
margin-left:170px;
}
```

As you will see if you try this code out locally and zoom out, the navigation starts breaking. Although when you try it on mobile devices it looks perfectly fine. Can someone please help me out with this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by adding the following to your `#nav li` style:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-ms-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box
```

This snippet was recycled from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1274647/2277682

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this should work.
Here is a jsfiddle of your nav bar:

http://jsfiddle.net/caedanlavender/97yGC/27/

I enclosed the entire nav bar in a div called "cont" and gave it a set height and width.

```
#cont{
 width:890px;
 height:34px;
 letter-spacing:-1px;
 font-family:Calibri;
 font-size:18px;
 letter-spacing:-0.5px;
 font-weight:500;
 }
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Although I do have another question, why does it not work without an extra '{'?

Comment: I have no idea, i didn't see it til you pointed it out just then. It could be that because it is an error it is stopping one part of the css working properly, in that case it means that you have unnecessary code. :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be caused by having widths and borders on the LI elements. When you zoom out the browser can reduce the widths, but the borders are already 1px so they can't get any smaller. As a result the total width of your LIs end up wider than your UL and the last LI drops to the next line.

If you move the borders to be on the A elements instead of LI everything should scale properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way to do this is by setting the li elements to `display: inline-block` and then using `white-space: nowrap`. This is  also a good idea because you don't want the text inside your buttons to break. However since the li elements are now inline you must not leave whitespace between them.

http://jsfiddle.net/eUR5H/1/