# Handling browser zoom (zoom causes wrapping)

Tags: html, css, zooming, word-wrap

I have an issue on my company's ecommerce site. On non-widescreen monitors, if you one of our pages while the browser is zoomed to 110% or higher, the layout gets messed up (specifically, the right side Div, which comprises 80% of the page (roughly) gets pushed below the left side div).

The site is built with the Smarty templating engine and uses pinnacle cart, but both have been heavily modified by the previous developer and myself. What can be done to improve the site's versatility with browser zoom? It wouldn't be an issue, except my boss alway has her browser zoomed to 110%.

Example page: http://www.buynowornever.com/handbags/ (but any page with the filters on the left side will do it).

There's obviously something wrong with the spacing on the page, such that when the browser attempts to reformat it in the zoom, the right div gets too large and overflows. I've tried correcting this with various overflow tricks, but have been unsuccessful.

I've looked through several answers here (including [How to prevent the floating layout wrapping when firefox zoom is reduced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274151/how-to-prevent-the-floating-layout-wrapping-when-firefox-zoom-is-reduced))  and on other sites and have not been able to make them work for my situation.  My CSS and Web Design skills are not very strong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was bad data.  Some of the category headers that I was using had close divs hidden in them.  This caused layout issues on some pages, but because of the hierarchy, was not utterly fatal (and chrome handles some of these problems pretty gracefully).  I cleared up the data issue and the pages all work as intended.....

I really should remember GIGO in these situations.